# apply function to 2d slices of a multidimensional NumPy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have 6D numpy array and I have a custom function that could be applied to a 2D array, the output is a 2D array of the same shape. I would like to iterate over all 2D arrays that are stored in the indexes 3 and 4, apply the custom function and return the 6D array with the shape of the original 6D array and with the data processed as described above with the custom function. I am currently using nested loops, but the process is awfully slow. Below is what I am currently doing (the size of the dimension 2 and 5 is 1, so no need to iterate over them).

```
orig_array = np.reshape(np.zeros(2**4), (2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1))
def custom_fun(array_2d):
    return array_2d + 1
out_array = np.copy(orig_array)
for ind1 in range(orig_array.shape[0]):
    for ind2 in range(orig_array.shape[1]):
        out_array[ind1, ind2, 0, :, :, 0] = custom_fun(out_array[ind1, ind2, 0, :, :, 0])
```

I was wondering if there is a way to vectorize this procedure with the aim of speeding up the computation.
I searched the NumPy documentation and found the function: np.apply_over_axes, however it does not seem to do what I would like.

Comment: How did you use `apply_over_axes` or how did it not work?

Comment: Also, this is going to be pretty specific to `custom_fun`. Having a toy stand-in may not be a good option. Some functions you write will be pretty easy to vectorize, others not so much.

Comment: @PavelZimin if you really just want to add 1 to certain elements (or some other simple arithmetic operation), it would be much easier to use [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) rather than explicitly trying to vectorise the operation. If this is not what you intend to do, please provide the exact `custom_fun` so that we can tailor our answer to best suit your use case.

Comment: `apply_over` won't help with speed.  As long as your function only works with 2d you are stuck with this speed.

Comment: The function I want to apply is very custom. The 2D slices are images, and the function is a rolling ball background reduction algorithm [link](https://github.com/mbalatsko/opencv-rolling-ball). The function must work on 2D.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, @RohanSaxena, @hpaulj The function I want to apply is very custom. The 2D slices are images, and the function is a rolling ball background reduction algorithm [link](https://github.com/mbalatsko/opencv-rolling-ball). The function must work on 2D. I tied   `np.apply_over_axes(custom_fun, orig_array, [3, 4])`, but it got an error from the custom function: `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`, when it tried to unpack the shape of 2D slice. So if `apply_over` does not help with the speed I could abandon this effort and continue with the nested loop solution.

Comment: We're all adults here. Very custom is not a thing, unless the code is proprietary

Comment: @MadPhysicist I added the link to the repo with the function. Please check it out if you would like to know the details.

Comment: Please don't make people go off-site to help you. You can edit the question any time to be complete.